# React Router Protected Routes firing before getting user token

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a React application that on `componentWillMount()` will trigger an action creator to fetch the current user from the stored token:

**App.js**

```
...
  async componentWillMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      await this.props.fetchUser();
    }
  }
...
```

Then, in the same `App.js` file, I have defined some routes. For simplicity I will display two routes:

**App.js**

```
...
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Reboot />
          <Route component={Header} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
          <ProtectedRoute
            isSignedIn={this.props.authenticated.jwtToken}
            path="/books"
            component={BookList}
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
...
```

In the `Header` component, I have a button that redirects to `/books` and when clicked, this correctly displays the books list when the user is logged in.

The problem comes when I try to go directly to the `http://localhost:3000/books` URL from the browser (i.e not by clicking the button). The `ProtectedRoute` component seems to render before the `fetchUser()` returns the `authenticated` state object, and will therefore redirect back to the main landing page.

This is the `ProtectedRoute` component:

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  jwtToken,
  isSignedIn,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isSignedIn ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: { from: props.location, message: "You need to sign in" }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

And this is the action creator for `fetchUser()`:

```
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  await dispatch({ type: FETCHING_USER });
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/api/current_user`, {
      headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem("token") }
    });
    await dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
  } catch (err) {
    // dispatch error action types
  }
};
```

I thought that by using the `async/await` syntax, I can maintain order and sequence of the dispatched actions...

Can someone illuminate me what I am doing wrong? Ideally I can get to the `/books` route directly from the browser without clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling an async action in `componentWillMount` will not prevent it from rendering until the action completes.

In your case, it's no different from doing it in `componentDidMount` (which is also why `componentWillMount` will be [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) in React 17).

You'd have to decide what to display to the user before `fetchUser` completes (which can take several seconds on a slow connection).
Perhaps a spinner?

Comment: The problem is that I still want a landing page to appear for guests. There are components which I want to be visible for guests.

Comment: When the user is authenticated initially, store a variable indicating it (could be just a boolean, or the username if you need to display it anyway) in the `localStorage`. Then use it as a flag to determine if a guest landing page or a previously-authenticated-but-pending-data-fetch page should be shown.

Comment: I used a slightly different technique, but will accept this as an answer as it pointed me to the right direction.